# React Router/Context API Search Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used to make this code work out for my search component but after the on submit is called, I receive this error which never happened before, does anyone have any clue???

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Consumer } from "../context";
class Search extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      productTitle: "",
      apiUrl: "*******************************",
      redirect: false
    };
  }

  findProduct = (dispatch, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post(
        `${this.state.apiUrl}`,
        JSON.stringify({ query: this.state.productTitle })
      )
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SEARCH_TRACKS",
          payload: res.data.output.items
        });

        this.setState({ items: res.data.output.items, redirect: true });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/searchresult" />;
    }
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {value => {
          const { dispatch } = value;
          return (
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.findProduct.bind(this, dispatch)}>
                <div className="form-group" id="form_div">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control form-control-md"
                    placeholder="...محصولات دسته یا برند مورد نظرتان را انتخاب کنید"
                    name="productTitle"
                    value={this.state.productTitle}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />

                  <button className="btn" type="submit">
                    <i className="fas fa-search" />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const Context = React.createContext();


export const axiosDashboard = () => {
  const URL = (`*****************`);
  return axios(URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({refresh:"true"}),
  })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });  
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
     case 'SEARCH_TRACKS':
       return {
         ...state,
         items: action.payload,
         heading: 'Search Results'
       };
   default:
     return state;
   }
}

export class Provider extends Component {
  state = { 
    dispatch:action => this.setState(state => reducer(state, action))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
         {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  }
}
export const Consumer = Context.Consumer
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Consumer } from '../context'
import SearchResult from './SearchResult'
import './Search.css'

class Tracks extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {value => {
           const { items } = value
             if(items === undefined || items.length === 0){
               return 'hello'}
             else{
               return(
                 <React.Fragment>
                   <div id='products_search'>
                     <div className='container'>
                       <div className="row justify-content-end">
                         {items.map(item => ( 
                           <SearchResult 
                             key={item.id} 
                             id={item.id} 
                             title={item.name} 
                             current_price={item.current_price} 
                             lowest_price={item.lowest_price} 
                             store_name={item.store_name} 
                             thumb={item.thumb_url}/>        
                          ))}
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </React.Fragment> 
                )
              }
          }}
      </Consumer>
    )
  }
}
export default Tracks
```

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import './Search.css'
const SearchResult = (props) => {
const {title,current_price,lowest_price,thumb,id,store_name} = props
return (
    <div className="col-md-3" id="searchresult">
        <img src={thumb} alt=""/>
        <div className="sexy_line"></div>
        <p className="muted">{store_name}</p>
        <h6>{title}</h6>
        <p>{lowest_price}</p>
        <Link to={`products/item/${id}`}>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-light rounded-pill">{
                    new Intl
                        .NumberFormat({style: 'currency', currency: 'IRR'})
                        .format(current_price)
                }</button>
        </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
export default SearchResult
```

Comment: Please show Tracks component

Comment: I put all that is related

Comment: Sorry, coudn't figure it out, and also, where do you render `Search` ?

Comment: in the last part of my code, the fourth one

Comment: You have two components, `Search` and `SearchResult`. I see that you render `SearchResult` in Tracks, but don't see where you render `Search`. Also in `Search` file, you aren't exporting the component.

Comment: all the props which are passed will be returned in the render

Answer (score 0):

> Maximum update depth exceeded.

This means that you are in a infinit loop of re rendering a component.

The only place where I can see this is possible to happen is in this part

```
if (redirect) {
    return <Redirect to="/searchresult" />;
}
```

Maybe you are redirecing to the a route that will get the same component that have the redirect.

Please check if you aren't redirecting to the same route as this component and provide your routes and what is inside `Consumer`.

Comment: I checked every piece of my code but the only place that this component is being redirected is this, I can put other my codes here, is it necessary?

Comment: Please add the rest of your code (routes and consumer) in your question